# Solve $\frac{dy}{dx} = f^{-1}(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am doing a differential equations subject, and have been given this as a challenge question.

Solve $\frac{dy}{dx} = f^{-1}(x)$

($f^{-1}(x)$ is the inverse function of x.)

I assume that the answer involves separable differential equations, but I can't quite see how to do it.

Is there a substitution that will help solve this?

#### Edit:

I've tried the following ideas:

#### Idea 1.

$$
\begin{align}
y &= \int f^{-1}(x) \, dx\\
\mathrm{let}\,\,u &= f^{-1}(x)\\
x &= f(u)\\
\frac{dx}{du} &= f'(u)\\
dx &= f'(u) \, \, du\\
\mathrm{so} \,\, y &= \int u f'(u)\, du\\
\end{align}
$$

Is this right, and if so, would I just integrate by parts?

Comment: The answer is clearly $y(x) = \int f^{-1}(x) dx + C$. Without any additional information on $f$, it can't be solved exactly.

Comment: Do you mean $y=f(x)$ i.e. $f'(x)=f^{-1}(x)$?

Comment: I've updated it with an idea that I've tried.

Comment: @daviewales You do not need to simplify it any further than what I wrote (and what you started off with). Any further manipulation is no simpler.

Comment: Yes @Anthony. I do mean $f'(x) = f^{-1}(x)$.

Comment: One of my other solutions was $y = Ae^x$. I can put up how I got to that as well if you like.

Comment: A simple sanity check (plug it back into the equation) should tell you you've made a mistake there.

Comment: Yes. That's what I thought.

Comment: You seem to be getting confused by using $y$ and $f(x)$ to represent the same function.  It would be better to pick one and stick with it.

Comment: Also, by $f^{-1}(x)$, do you mean the inverse of $f(x)$?

Comment: Have a look at this MO page: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/34052/function-satisfying-f-1-f. Looks like there are a great number of local solutions; I'd be interested if anyone could determine the existence of general solutions defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$.

Comment: I'm going to remove the second example. @Antonio, I mean inverse f(x) = f'(x).

Comment: @Anthony See my (revised) answer for half of your question.

Answer (score 1):

I misunderstood earlier - sorry.

FWIW, there is no such function defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$.

If there were, by referring to the derivative at all I would assume that we would be looking for a continuous function (say as opposed to one continuous almost everywhere). And by referring to an inverse I would assume that we would be looking for a one-to-one function (as opposed to a function with a restricted inverse.)

Since the domain of $f$ would be all of $\mathbb{R}$, the range of $f^{-1}$ is all of $\mathbb{R}$ too. Then since $f'=f^{-1}$, $f$ is sometimes increasing, sometimes decreasing. This is not possible for a one-to-one continuous function.

Comment: $f^{-1}$ is referring to the inverse function, not the reciprocal.

Comment: @Anthony is right. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this **Hint**.

> Theorem: Let $f$ be a one-to-one function with inverse $f^{-1}$. Suppose $f$ be differentiable at a point $x$, with $f'(x)\ne0$ and moreover suppose $f^{-1}$ is continuous at $f(x)=y$. Then $$(f^{-1})'=\frac{1}{f'(x)}$$

In fact, $$\frac{dx}{dy}\cdot f'(x)=1$$ Now think of this ODE instead, $$y'=f^{-1}\longrightarrow x'\cdot x=1$$

Comment: I think you need to be more careful about the points of evaluation - the original equation is evaluating $f^{-1}(x)$ and $f'(x)$, so we get $f^{-1}(x)(f^{-1})'(f(x))=1$, which is still not an ODE.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis: I assumed that $f^{-1}$ is expressed wit respect to $x$ not $y$ here.